# xsl template and variables mix use with html

Tags: html, xslt

My problem is when i mix html elements in my xsl stylesheets, i am confused in what i am generating as the XML parses just complains:

```
Error on line 1 column 1 
  SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Premature end of file.
```

Here's my code

```
<xsl:template match="myTemplate">
    <xsl:variable name="fieldtype" select="Radio"/>

            &lt;td width="100px"&gt;&lt;span style="word-wrap: break-word"&gt;          
             <xsl:value-of select="$fieldtype"/>&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
</xsl:template>
```

Will this show up as

```
<td width="100px"><span style="word-wrap:break word">Radio</span></td>
```

Comment: Can you show us your whole XSLT file or show us the issue in an [XML Playground](http://www.xmlplayground.com) session?

Comment: unfortunately my XSLT process is super huge like 6 files of 1000 lines each, and i dont have the xml as our client deems that confidential :\  anways, thanks for the help, i'll flag this issue to my boss as empty data and see where it goes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd need to encode the HTML. There's nothing special about the HTML you've shown us that would prevent it from being parsed as valid XHTML.

If for some reason you must encode the HTML, it might be safer to assign the attributes using `xsl:attribute`.

```
<xsl:template match="myTemplate">
    <xsl:variable name="fieldtype" select="Radio"/>
    <td>
        <xsl:attribute name="width">
            <xsl:text>100px</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <span>
            <xsl:attribute name="style">
                <xsl:text>word-wrap: break-word</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="$fieldtype"/>
        </span>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks reason why i encoded html as it's a template used by our 3rd-party provider...nothing much i can do. btw can you please upvote my questions and i'll accept your answer. cheers.